# How to pass checkboxes in different activities to one single activity in android?

Tags: android, android-intent

I am making an android app in which there are different cities in different activities.
For example, there is one activity for dalhousie and another activity for Shimla.
And in each activity there is one heart shaped like checkbox, like in Instagram. If we check the check boxes, then the city will appear in another activity say ProfileActivity.java which has a list of all the favorite cities that i have checked. I don't know how to get the intent from different activities into one single activity.

Here is my code for DalhousieActivity.java

```
package com.example.srushtee.dummy;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.method.ScrollingMovementMethod;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.TextView;

import me.relex.circleindicator.CircleIndicator;

public class DalhousieActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ViewPager viewPager;
private CustomSwipeAdapter adapter;
private static int currentpage = 0;
private int[] img;
private CheckBox favouriteBtn;
private TextView textview;
boolean flag=false;
private Button continueBooking;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_dalhousie);
    boolean isChecked = getBooleanFromPreferences("isChecked");
    img = new int[]{R.drawable.dalhousie, R.drawable.dalhousie3, R.drawable.dalhousie2, R.drawable.dalhousie1};
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
    adapter = new CustomSwipeAdapter(DalhousieActivity.this, img);
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    CircleIndicator indicator = (CircleIndicator) findViewById(R.id.indicator);
    indicator.setViewPager(viewPager);

    viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            currentpage = 1;

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int i) {
            if (i == viewPager.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
                int pagecount = img.length;
                if (currentpage == 0) {
                    viewPager.setCurrentItem(pagecount - 1, false);
                } else if (currentpage == pagecount - 1) {
                    viewPager.setCurrentItem(0, false);
                }

            }

        }
    });

    favouriteBtn = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.buttonfav);
    Log.i("start", "" + isChecked);
    favouriteBtn.setChecked(isChecked);
    favouriteBtn.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton view, boolean isChecked) {
            Log.i("boolean", "" + isChecked);
            DalhousieActivity.this.putBooleanInPreferences(isChecked, "isChecked");
            flag=true;
            Intent i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ProfileActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("Dalhousie",flag);


        }
    });
   continueBooking=(Button) findViewById(R.id.continue_booking);
    continueBooking.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i=new Intent(DalhousieActivity.this,ConfirmationActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
        }
    });


}





public void putBooleanInPreferences(boolean isChecked,String key){
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = this.getPreferences(Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putBoolean(key, isChecked);
    editor.commit();
}
public boolean getBooleanFromPreferences(String key){
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = this.getPreferences(Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
    Boolean isChecked = sharedPreferences.getBoolean(key, false);
    return isChecked;
}
}
```

and here is my code for ProfileActivity.class

```
package com.example.srushtee.dummy;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Process;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ProfileActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mToggle;

private boolean backPressedToExitOnce;
private boolean doubleBackToExitPressedOnce;
 private NavigationView navigationView;
private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
private Button upload_btn;
boolean flag=false;
ListView listView;
String favName;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);
    firebaseAuth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    if(firebaseAuth==null)
    {
        finish();
        startActivity(new Intent(this,MainActivity.class));
    }
    FirebaseUser user=firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();



   getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
      navigationView=(NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new 
  NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            if(item.isChecked()) item.setChecked(false);
            else item.setChecked(true);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
            switch(item.getItemId())
            {
                case R.id.nav_account:
                    Toast.makeText(ProfileActivity.this,"called account",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    //startActivity(new Intent(ProfileActivity.this,Account.class));
                    return true;
                case R.id.nav_LogOut:
                    signout();
                    return true;
                case R.id.nav_cities:
                    startActivity(new Intent(ProfileActivity.this,CitiesActivity.class));
                    return true;


                default:
                    Toast.makeText(ProfileActivity.this,"default",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return true;
            }
        }
    });

    ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,mDrawerLayout,R.string.open, R.string.close){

        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
            // Code here will be triggered once the drawer closes as we dont want anything to happen so we leave this blank
            super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            // Code here will be triggered once the drawer open as we dont want anything to happen so we leave this blank

            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
        }
    };
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);
    mToggle=new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,mDrawerLayout,R.string.open,R.string.close);
    mDrawerLayout.addDrawerListener(mToggle);
    mToggle.syncState();
    mToggle.setToolbarNavigationClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        }
    });



    //List<list_item> data = new ArrayList<>();
   /* for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
        list_item item = new list_item();
        item.setImageResId(place_image[j]);
        item.setTitle(place_name[j]);
        item.setId(place_name[j]);
        item.setStatus(place_desc[j]);
        data.add(item);
    }

    list_data = (ArrayList) data;

    //data stored and retrieved until now

    rec_view = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.places_recyler_view);
    rec_view.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    adapter = new derp_adapter(data, this);
    rec_view.setAdapter(adapter);

    adapter.setItemClickCallback(this);*/

    upload_btn=(Button) findViewById(R.id.upload_photo_btn);
    upload_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(ProfileActivity.this,UploadPhotoActivity.class));
        }
    });








}

private void signout() {
    if(firebaseAuth!=null)
    {
        firebaseAuth.signOut();
    }
    finish();
    startActivity(new Intent(this,MainActivity.class));

}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if(mToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item))
    {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (doubleBackToExitPressedOnce) {
        moveTaskToBack(true);
        Process.killProcess(Process.myPid());
        System.exit(1);

    }
    this.doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = true;
    Toast.makeText(this, "Press again to Exit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = false;
        }
    }, 1000);

}
}
```

Comment: use sharedpreferences or sqlite to store favorite cities.

Comment: you have to save name of your city also into shared preference  and load it to next activity and base on that name check your button as favorite in that activity.

Comment: can you please give me the code for it? it would be a lot helpful